# Asses Utxos Time In On-Chain Code

Tags: plutus

Can you assess the time a Utxo was created in on-chain code?

i.e. A transaction to a smart contract that can claim  only Utxos - in that contract address - sent in a specific time period?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that is possible with `cardano-db-sync`.

Every new UTxO is created by a transaction, which is part of a block and the block will have a timestamp.

Comment: is that something queriable from the script context for any utxo input in the tx to the validator?

Comment: I was wondering if is something than can be extrapolated from script context with PlutusTx, so provable from the script/validator itself, but I don't think so